# OAuth2 authentication in CakePHP 3 using muffin plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth

I'm currently working on a CakePHP 3 application, trying to connect to Microsoft Azure using OAuth2. To this end, I'm trying to integrate the [UseMuffin OAuth2 plugin](https://github.com/usemuffin/oauth2). However, I'm struggling with the documentation. It seems to describe how to configure the plugin, but not how to actually use it. What methods do I call and how when I want to initiate an OAuth2 authentication? I'm somewhat familiar with OAuth2 itself, already wrote a little stand-alone PHP script that successfully authenticates using Curl. I'm just not sure how the UseMuffin plugin can help.

To be clear, the CakePHP 3 application I'm working on already has its own authentication scheme. I just want some users (not all) that are already authenticated with my application, to connect with Azure, so we can exchange information. I'm not sure the UseMuffin plugin can work alongside an existing means of authentication?

Comment: More specifically, in the Muffin plugin documentation, under the header 'Usage' it goes from: "First, start by defining the providers:" to "Upon successful authorization, ..."  I feel like there are some steps missing in between there.

Comment: The plugin is a (more or less) drop-in authentication object for use with CakePHPs built-in [**authentication component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html), so AFAICT there shouldn't be any additional steps, other than setting up the auth component, but that's not the plugins concern. You may get better help if you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "_so we can exchange information_".

Comment: Thanks! Reading your comment I get an increasing feeling that the UseMuffin plugin is not the tool I am looking for. The CakePHP application I'm working on is an API itself and it already has an Authcomponent to authenticate our users. What I want is to allow some of our authenticated users to connect with their Microsoft 365 account (through OAuth), authorizing us to submit data on their behalf to their Microsoft 365 account.